# Sharepoint Online Workflow restart error (Console Application)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I frequently get requests to restart a workflow for some of my list items. I have written an application which takes library name and list item name as an input. when i try to start a workflow (StartWorkflow method) i get this error Exception from HRESULT: 0x8102009B and no inner exception. Below is my code.

Sometimes the workflow may have already been started. In that case i need to cancel the workflow and then restart.

I did lot of search on this issue. Most of the resolution is for SP 2010. We are using SP Online

```
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Userid, Password);
var web = clientContext.Web;
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("listname");
clientContext.Load(list);

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' Descending='True'/></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='File'>" + ListItemName + ".xml</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
                ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var id = items.Where(a => a.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"].ToString() == ListItemName + ".xml").Select(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
Guid listItemID = (Guid)items.Where(a => a.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"].ToString() == ListItemName + ".xml").Select(a => a.FieldValues["GUID"]).FirstOrDefault();

WorkflowAssociationCollection wfaCollection = items.Where(a => a.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"].ToString() == ListItemName + ".xml")
                                                .Select(a => a.ParentList.WorkflowAssociations).FirstOrDefault();
clientContext.Load(wfaCollection);

                var workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(clientContext, web);
clientContext.Load(workflowServiceManager);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    InteropService workflowInteropService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInteropService();
clientContext.Load(workflowInteropService);


                var wfaName = wfaCollection.Where(a => a.Enabled == true).Select(a => a.Name).FirstOrDefault();
Guid wfaId = wfaCollection.Where(a => a.Enabled == true).Select(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
var initiationData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

ClientResult<Guid> resultGuid = workflowInteropService.StartWorkflow(wfaName, new Guid(), list.Id, listItemID, initiationData);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Did anyone got a chance to look at the above issue ?

Comment: did you find any solution? I am having the same issue!

Comment: nope. I did not find any solution.

Comment: I have solved my problem. Let me know if you need my solution

Comment: Please do share...this will help a lot

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XaSidfuE